# How to execute python commands from a conda .yaml specification file?

Tags: python-3.x, yaml, conda, azure-machine-learning-service

I am trying to list conda dependencies using a .yaml file for an AzureML [environment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-deploy-and-where?tabs=python#define-an-inference-configuration). I do not want to use a custom docker image just for a few variations. I wonder if there is a way to instruct the build to run python commands using the .yaml file. Here are excerpts of what I have tried as of now:

```
name: classifer_environment
dependencies:
- python=3.6.2

- pip:
  - azureml-defaults>=1.0.45
  - nltk==3.4.5
  - spacy

- command: 
  - bash -c "python -m nltk.downloader stopwords"
  - bash -c "python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm"
```

I also tried this:

```
name: classifer_environment
dependencies:
- python=3.6.2

- pip:
  - azureml-defaults>=1.0.45
  - nltk==3.4.5
  - spacy

- python: 
  - nltk.downloader stopwords
  - spacy download en_core_web_sm
```

I do not have much clarity about yaml specifications. Both the specifications fail with the following messages respectively in the build logs: 
"Unable to install package for command." 
"Unable to install package for python."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be a neat feature to have, but for now it's not a thing - at least not directly in the YAML like this.

Instead, the unit of computation in Conda is the *package*. That is, if you need to run additional scripts or commands at environment creation, it can be achieved by building a custom package and including this package in the YAML as a dependency. The package itself could be pretty much empty, but whatever code one needs to run would be included via [some installation scripts](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda-build/en/latest/resources/link-scripts.html).

Comment: can a similar implementation be done via a python wheel?